# how to make view console in table content

Tags: php, javascript, html

i try to make a simple table in my web like usually. but i have no idea how to make a display for edit and view another content according to this each table content.

```
<body>
<table width="1023" height="248" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A1</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A2</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A3</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A4</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A5</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A6</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A7</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A8</th>
    <th colspan="2" scope="col">A9</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><div align="center">A1.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A1.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A2.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A3.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A4.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A5.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A6.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A7.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A8.8</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.4</div></td>
    <td><div align="center">A9.8</div></td>
  </tr>
</body>
```

my concept, when the pointer of user close to 1 content of table, the display automaticlly shown for act view or input new data. Please advice

for exp. like on view gmail web client. when user cursore close to one of name sender email in inbox, the console automaticly shown for add contact etc..but in gmail just for the name of sender

Comment: Hi. Clarify please what you want to do when user pointer close to table cell ?

Comment: hi...for this step just display a console for view and edit menu. the next step i wil modify it according to the answer

Comment: display a console - what is this mean ? you mean display some input field ?

Comment: an interface for another act

Comment: got it, thanks. wait a sec i'll write an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem by pure javascript or jquery :

javascript solution

```
//this function create our layout which will be displayed on mouse over
function createOverlay(){
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = "your own code here";
div.id = "overlay";
div.display="none";
div.style.position="absolute";
div.style.border="1px solid";
document.body.appendChild(div);
}

//this function show layout
function showOverlay(el){
if(!document.getElementById("overlay"))
createOverlay();
var div = document.getElementById("overlay");
div.style.display="block";
div.style.width="200px";
div.style.height="200px";
div.style.top = parseInt(el.offsetTop)+"px";
div.style.left=parseInt(el.offsetLeft)+parseInt(div.style.width)/4+"px";
div.onmouseover = function(event){event.stopPropagation();return false;}
}

// and this function hide - you can use it for "close" button on overlay
function hideOverlay(){
document.getElementById("overlay").style.display="none";
}

here is the code which add event handlers to td elements of your table
var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
var tds = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
var flag=true;
if(document.getElementById("overlay")){
if(document.getElementById("overlay").style.display!="none")
flag=false;
}
for(i in tds){
tds[i].onmouseover = function(event){if(flag){showOverlay(this);event.stopPropagation()}else{return false;}};
}
```

Here we handle the onmouseover event on each td element and when it happens - show the overlay ( div ) which can contain any HTML code

Also you can add background to div, and edit position of div by editing this lines

```
div.style.top = parseInt(el.offsetTop)+"px";
div.style.left=parseInt(el.offsetLeft)+parseInt(div.style.width)/4+"px";
```

You can also do this thing by JQuery and it will be less code :)

Also i recommend you to read about events in javascript

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the the display only in button if we add more than one content.
like this one 
http://jsfiddle.net/f4SHq/

Comment: Thanks for the answer..i wan to know how to manipulate the position of overlay. the other problem it's not running in browser but i did it in
http://jsfiddle.net/andricoga/yTj8K/ it's work please advise

Comment: div.style.top = parseInt(el.offsetTop)+"px";
div.style.left=parseInt(el.offsetLeft)+parseInt(div.style.width)/4+"px"


this code is manipulate the position. for example you can replace 
div.style.top = parseInt(el.offsetTop)+"px" to
div.style.top = parseInt(el.offsetTop)+10+"px"; - it will move div to 10px down

same thing with the left
div.style.left=parseInt(el.offsetLeft)+parseInt(div.style.width)/4+"px";

what we do here - we take the left top point of hovered td then we take x from this point and add 1/4 of our div width.

what about browser - what kind of browser you using ?

Comment: Always use `parseInt(whatev, 10)`. Too many silly mistakes happen with that second parameter missing. I really wish it were required.

Comment: @AlexZ i want to know how to make the content for view and edit

Comment: Please clarify..what do you mean under content for view and edit ?

Comment: something like this https://www.dropbox.com/lightbox/home/Photos/Sample%20Album (new picture28.bmp)
and then i want add a eventns that overlay jus show when the moouse point precisely at the text

Comment: Looks like links to dropbox is wrong. Can you please share link to this picture 28 ? For this just click to share link (it is the last icon in image row ) and  in the new page click share button

Comment: i hope this work https://www.dropbox.com/s/as4ssn0svmmftgn/New%20Picture%20%2828%29.bmp

Comment: @AlexZ tq for the answer please my new Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715913/how-to-make-the-table-content-wil-shown-automaticly-in-pop-up-form