# how to make the table content wil shown automaticly in pop up form

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql-server-2008

i try to make a table in my web. Table content have value that i use for parameter in the next action and automaticly shown on form. 
here my skenario

the content of the table as button for my popup like this

```
  <div>
    <table width="1023" height="248" border="1">
      <tr>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">A1</th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">A2</th>
        <th colspan="2" scope="col">A3</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A1.4" /></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A1.8" /></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A2.4" /></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A2.8" /></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A3.4" /></td>
        <td><div align="center"><input type="button" onclick="popup_window_show('#sample', { pos : 'tag-right-down',   parent : this, width : '270px' });" value="A3.8" /></td>
     </tr>
</div>
```

this my popup_window_show

```
  <div   class="popup_window_css" id="sample">
    <div   class="popup_window_css_head"><img src="images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />Aksi</div>
    <div   class="popup_window_css_body"><div style="border: 1px solid #808080; padding: 6px; background: #FFFFFF;">
    <form method="post" action="">
    <table width="200">
        <tr>
         <td colspan='2' align='center'> WHK </td>
        <tr>
         <td> Posisi :</td>
         <td> <input type='text' name="p" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td> Product ID :</td>
         <td> <input type='text' name="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td> Product Name :</td>
         <td> <input type='text' name="nama" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td> Production Date :</td>
         <td> <input type='text' name="tgl" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan='2' align='right'>
             <input type='submit' value= 'Save'> 
             <input type='reset' value='Reset' />
             <input type='button' value='view' onclick=\"window.location.href='#';\"/>
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

my focus problem how to make the table content will shown automaticly in popup form at Posisi coloumn.
ex: when the user clik A1.4 so in "posisi" coloumn automaticly have value A1.4 and displayed

And then when user click view button, "web" guide the user to a new page that displayed database which table content as parameter. 
may be this http://jsfiddle.net/andricoga/k4BB3/#base can help to understand my problem

my english still weak, i hope you understand what i mean and give solve for me tq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes i find that

```
<script>
        function setvalue(values) {
        document.getElementById('posisi').value = values;
    }
    </script>
    <div>
        <table width="1023" height="248" border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>

                        <input type="button" onclick="setvalue(this.value);" value="A1.8" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="popup_window_css" id="sample">
            <table class="popup_window_css">
                <tr class="popup_window_css">
                    <td class="popup_window_css">
                        <div class="popup_window_css_head">
                            <img src="images/close.gif" alt="" width="9" height="9" />Aksi</div>
                        <div class="popup_window_css_body">
                            <div style="border: 1px solid #808080; padding: 6px; background: #FFFFFF;">
                                <form method="post" action="">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>Werehouse</td>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Posisi</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type='text' name="p" id="posisi" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Product ID</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type='text' name="id" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Product Name</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type='text' name="nama" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>Production Date</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <input type='text' name="tgl" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td colspan='2' align='right'>
                                                    <input type='submit' value='Save'>
                                                    <input type='reset' value='Reset' />
                                                    <input type='button' value='view' onclick=\ "window.location.href='#';\"/>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                    </table>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

you can cek here http://jsfiddle.net/JLExZ/